# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Tags: java, spring, maven

Guys when I start my spring application I get an error and Tomcat server does not start.
Here's my work below (In main app, reading part and hibernate part are  working fine)

Main Application

```
package com.javainuse;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootHelloWorldApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {         
                System.out.println("Debug Print");
                 Read();


        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.class, args);

    }

    private static void Read() throws IOException {
          System.out.println("Hacked by?");
        SessionFactory sf = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/MONSTER/Desktop/Hello.xlsx")); 
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file); 
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
        Row row;
        for(int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){ 
            row = (Row) sheet.getRow(i);  //sheet number


                String id;
                if( row.getCell(0)==null) { id = "0"; }
                else id= row.getCell(0).toString();

                   String name;
                if( row.getCell(1)==null) { name = "null";}  
                   else name = row.getCell(1).toString();   //else copies cell data to name variable

                   String phone;
                if( row.getCell(2)==null) { phone = "null";   }
                   else  phone   = row.getCell(2).toString();
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        Customer std = new Customer();
        std.setId((int) Double.parseDouble(id));
        std.setName(name);
        std.setPhone(phone);
        System.out.println(std.getId()+" "+std.getName()+" "+std.getPhone());
        session.saveOrUpdate(std);
        t.commit();     
        }

        file.close();
                System.out.println("Completed!");

    }



    }
```

Customer class

```
package com.javainuse;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="customer", schema="excel")
public class Customer  {
    @Id
 //  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
        @Column
private String name;
        @Column
private String phone;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}
public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
public Customer(int id, String name, String phone) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
}
public Customer() {
    super();
}





}
```

Controller

```
package com.javainuse.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class helloController {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome.html")
    public ModelAndView firstPage() {
        return new ModelAndView("xd"); 
    }

}
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>YEA</groupId>
    <artifactId>YEA</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>YEA</name>
    <description>Demo YEA for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1B</version>
</dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.4.RELEASE</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>3.14</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>3.14</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't declared any `DataSource`. You have two options:

1. Use [Spring Boot JPA Starter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html).
2. Configure your own `DataSource`, e.g. like below ().

   ```
   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource(){
       DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
       dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
       dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:");
       dataSource.setUsername("sa");
       dataSource.setPassword("");

       return dataSource;
   };
   ```

Answer (score 1):

According to logs you need to create DataSource bean to connect to database you are using. E.g. somewhere in your configuration you need to define datasource bean:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    ...
}
```